# Django: 'ContactView' object has no attribute 'form'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to follow this tutorial (https://hellowebapp.com/news/introduction-to-class-based-views/) and have made this view:

```
class ContactView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
    template_name = 'app/contact.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        contact_name = self.form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
        contact_email = self.form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
        form_content = self.form.cleaned_data['content']

        template = get_template('contact_template.txt')
        context = Context({
            'contact_name': contact_name,
            'contact_email': contact_email,
            'form_content': form_content
        })
        content = template.render(context)

        email = EmailMessage(
            'New contact form submission',
             content,
             'Your website ' + '',
             ['youremail@gmail.com'],
             headers={'Reply-To': contact_email}
        )
        email.send()
        return super(ContactView, self).form_valid(form)
```

However when I submit the form I get the following error:
`'ContactView' object has no attribute 'form'`

The error seems to be related to this part:

```
  contact_name = self.form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
  contact_email = self.form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
  form_content = self.form.cleaned_data['content']
```

where 'form' is an unresolved reference.

How do I fix this error? Any help is much appreciated!
I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be `form` instead of `self.form` (since the form instance is passed as a parameter to the function).

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    contact_name = form.cleaned_data['contact_name']
    contact_email = form.cleaned_data['contact_email']
    form_content = form.cleaned_data['content']
    ...
```